# How can I find the current Rust compiler's default LLVM target triple?

Tags: rust, llvm

I want to [override a build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#overriding-build-scripts), which means adding a configuration section that looks like this:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.foo]
rustc-link-search = ["/path/to/foo"]
rustc-link-lib = ["foo"]
root = "/path/to/foo"
key = "value"
```

But I'm using a Mac, so `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` isn't the correct target triple.

How do I discover which target triple rustc or cargo are currently using?

`rustc --print cfg` prints a list of values that don't seem to correspond to the triple (there's no `unknown` in there, in particular).

`rustc --print target-list` displays all available targets; I just want the default.

Comment: The target triple for your Mac probably is `x86_64-apple-darwin`.  The middle part is the vendor, which for Linux is `unknown`, but for a Mac it's `apple`. However, it appears you want to configure the build script independent of the target, so you shouldn't need the target triple at all.

Comment: Yeah, I found the correct answer by looking at the list -- found the two `darwin` targets, and knew I was on `x86_64`, but that still requires me to think. Can you expand on "shouldn't need the target triple at all"?

Answer (score 13):

Based on @konstin [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66955420/377927):

```sh
$ rustc -vV | sed -n 's|host: ||p'
```

which gives you something like:

```
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 8):

cargo uses `rustc -vV` to detect the default target triple ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/1dae5acb7d27568ca30fe2da49b4a447d7b78e90/src/cargo/util/rustc.rs#L50-L68)). We can do the same thing:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

use anyhow::{format_err, Context, Result};
use std::str;

fn get_target() -> Result<String> {
    let output = Command::new("rustc")
        .arg("-vV")
        .output()
        .context("Failed to run rustc to get the host target")?;
    let output = str::from_utf8(&output.stdout).context("`rustc -vV` didn't return utf8 output")?;

    let field = "host: ";
    let host = output
        .lines()
        .find(|l| l.starts_with(field))
        .map(|l| &l[field.len()..])
        .ok_or_else(|| {
            format_err!(
                "`rustc -vV` didn't have a line for `{}`, got:\n{}",
                field.trim(),
                output
            )
        })?
        .to_string();
    Ok(host)
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let host = get_target()?;
    println!("target triple: {}", host);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Pass the compiler output through awk for the triple:

$ rustc -vV | awk '/host/ { print $2 }'
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 3):

I write a lot of cross-platform shell scripts or Python programs that need to check my current Rust default target triple. I don't like manually grepping the string value, though.

To make it easier to get the default target triple, I packaged [konstin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66955420) into a command line tool.

You can install it with:

```
cargo install default-target
```

and then you can use the program just by running:

```
default-target
```

and it'll return your current target triple. Something like `x86_64-apple-darwin` or `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

You can find more details about the crate on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/default-target/), [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/default-target), and [GitHub](https://github.com/neocrym/default-target).

Comment: You might want to switch it from calling `rustc -vV` to using https://crates.io/crates/current_platform - that's faster and does not require you to locate the rustc binary.

Comment: @Shnatsel, it's an interesting idea. But if I embed the target triple in `default-target` at compile time, is it possible that the `rustc` target triple becomes different? e.g. Could the same machine have some binaries as `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` and other binaries as `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`?

Comment: Yes, that's possible - if you use rustup, you can switch what your default target is. rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html
I'm not sure if that shows up in `rustc -vV` either

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`current_platform`](https://crates.io/crates/current_platform) crate:

```rust
use current_platform::CURRENT_PLATFORM;

fn main() {
    println!("Running on {}", CURRENT_PLATFORM);
}
```

This will print `Running on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` on desktop Linux.

Unlike all the other answers, this is **zero cost:** the platform is determined at compile time, so there is no runtime overhead. By contrast, calls to `rustc` are expensive: if Rust is installed through rustup.rs, any `rustc` command takes ~100ms.

Answer (score 2):

With a recent enough rustc compiler:

```
$ rustc -Z unstable-options --print target-spec-json | grep llvm-target
```

Comment: Hmm. `error: the option \`Z\` is only accepted on the nightly compiler` (rustc 1.42.0).

Comment: You can always add `+nightly`, i.e.  `rustc +nightly -Z unstable-options --print target-spec-json | grep llvm-target`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me (inspired by rodrigo's answer)

```
RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1 rustc -Z unstable-options --print target-spec-json | python3 -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print(obj["llvm-target"])'
```

RUSTC_BOOTSTRAP=1 bypasses the check that normally allows certain features to only be used on the nightly branch. I also used a proper json parser rather than grep.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly elegant perhaps, but I found this to work:

```
rustup show | grep default | grep -Po "^[^-]+-\K\S+"
```

Comment: While the filtering commands are not very elegant, the usage of `rustup show` seems better than accepted answer. Specifically because rustup is rust's installer.